# How to recognize order of values in column in Python Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["ADRESAT"] = ["Kowal Jan", "Nowak Adam PHU"]
df["NADAWCA"] = ["Jan Kowal", "Adam Nowak"]
```

And I had created 2 new columns:

- col1 - value from column "NADAWCA" which is in column "ADRESAT"
- col2 - rest of values (values from column "ADRESAT" beyon values which are also in column "NADAWCA")

  df["col2"] = df.apply(lambda r: re.sub(r["NADAWCA"], '', r["ADRESAT"], flags = re.IGNORECASE).strip(), axis=1)
  df["col1"] = df["NADAWCA"].str.title()

Nevertheless, as a result I have df like below. But as you can see in second row there is a mistake.

- In col1 is ok (value from column "NADAWCA" which are also in column "ADRESAT" but
- in col2 I need to have only PHU (means values from column "ADRESAT" beyond valyes which ares also in column "NADAWCA")

[image]

My question: How to modify my code so as to recognize that Adam Nowak and Nowak Adam is the same value ?

I need result as below :

[image]

Comment: Why `col2` of line1 (Kowal Jan) is not empty in your expected output?

Comment: yeas you are right it shoudl be empty, I will change it

Comment: In col2 need to be value from ADRESAT minus value from NADAWCA, so If you have Jan Kowal in NADAWCA and Kowal Jan in ADRESAT (it is the same in other order) col2 is empty, but in terms of second row PHU is is the only one value from ADRESAT which is not in NADAWCA and there is reason why PHU is in col2 in row 2

Comment: My problem is how to tell Python (using my code or other proposition) that Adam Nowak and Nowak Adam is the same value

Comment: Ok. it's better now :-) I'll write a solution soon.

Comment: Great! I'm really counting on your help :)

Comment: In the `col1` the order is important or not?

Comment: In col1 there is preferably to have order like in NADAWCA, so if I have in NADAWCA Jan Kowal -> in col1 also Jan Kowal not Kowal Jan :)

Comment: So to answer in one word - Yes, order is important in col1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the order does matter, using `set` is not possible, So we need to check each word one by one:

```
# x[0] -> ADRESAT, x[1] -> NADAWCA
intersection = lambda x: ' '.join([x1 for x1 in x[1].split()
                             if x1.lower() in x[0].lower().split()])

difference = lambda x: ' '.join([x0 for x0 in x[0].split()
                           if not x0.lower() in x[1].lower().split()])

df['col1'] = df[['ADRESAT', 'NADAWCA']].apply(intersection, axis='columns')
df['col2'] = df[['ADRESAT', 'NADAWCA']].apply(difference, axis='columns')
```

```
>>> df
          ADRESAT     NADAWCA        col1 col2
0       Kowal Jan   Jan Kowal   Jan Kowal
1  Nowak Adam PHU  Adam Nowak  Adam Nowak  PHU
```

Comment: Great! probably works correctly but I will check it better for a moment and eventuallly I will write :) As I see case of letter is not important ,yeas ? :)

Comment: Is that answer correct for Python 3.7.4 ? Corralien ? :)

Comment: You right. Feel free to remove `lower` to get a case sensitive comparison (or use `casefold` to compare characters like 'ß' to 'ss'.

Comment: I don't know for 3.7.4 but it works for 3.6.9 and 3.9.5 :)